# Badge on launcher icon for nexus, asus , or some of devices having OS above 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, badge

How to implement badge on the application launcher icon, i implemented badge with the help of some of link like below

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html

http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/11/android-get-ios-style-badge-app-icon.html

http://sonuasher89.blogspot.in/2013/11/android-pushnotification-badge-icon.html

But these all runs only on devices having OS below 5.0
How to make it run above that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Android does not support badges on application launcher icons at the OS level. Nor do most home screens support badges on application launcher icons. A few home screens do offer this, though rarely in a documented or supported fashion.

Comment: Yes I Believe showing badge is not the default feature for Android like IOS but then How facebook app showing badge on every android Devices? there should be some solution, some libraries i found but that only run on Android Devices below 5.0. Please suggest...